# Susy, proper way to put page left and right margins

Tags: susy

I am trying to use susy in one of my web sites.  I have set susy map settings with a 12 column layout i have gutters ( right margins ) between columns... What is the proper way to give the 'container' a left and right margin ( or padding )?

Answer (score 0):

As per Susy reference (http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/settings/#container) you can either use `container: 80%` in your map, or use `@include container(80%);`

We use `@include container` in media queries to have different container sizes. :)